# How to get ComboBox ItemIndex before OnChange event?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7

I have a TComboBox in my Delphi 7 form with some Items in it.
In the `OnChange` event, I do some processing depending on what Item was selected, but during this processing I may want to revert to the previous selected Item.

Programmatically, I want something like

```
ComboBox.ItemIndex := oldItemIndex;
```

The problem is I don't know how to get the `oldItemIndex`.

I tried defining a (global) variable in the `OnCloseUp` event, but ItemIndex there is already the new selected ItemIndex.
I also tried saving `oldItemIndex` on `OnEnter` event. While this works for saving the `oldItemIndex` the first time the control gets focused, it does not works if the focus is kept in it, thus effectively only working the first time the item changes.

**What's the easiest way to get the last selected item in a ComboBox when inside the OnChange event handler?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

one way to do this is like this :

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FPriorIndex : integer;
  public
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showmessage(ComboBox1.Items[FPriorIndex]);
  FPriorIndex := ComboBox1.ItemIndex;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
  FPriorIndex := ComboBox1.ItemIndex;
end;
```

**How to do it without variable outside the OnChange event:**

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
const
  PRIOR_INDEX : integer = 0;
begin
  showmessage(ComboBox1.Items[PRIOR_INDEX]);
  PRIOR_INDEX := ComboBox1.ItemIndex;
end;
```

For this to work you need to open your project options / Compiler and check "Assignable typed constants"

Comment: I did something like that, but was wondering if there's a way that do not involves using a variable outside `OnChange`'s scope.

Comment: @ricardomenzer I edited my answer to include a way to do it without a variable outside the onchange event

Comment: That was what I was talking about. Really good solution. Answer accepted. Thanks.